# Query all databases on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a dozen or so Azure databases provisioned on a single server SQL Server.  Each database has a table that records the application version of the db.

Can I run a single query that will return the single value from each db?

Something like this:

```
USE master
SELECT 'db1', Value FROM [db1].[meta].[DatabaseSettings] WHERE Entry = 'Version'
UNION SELECT 'db2', Value FROM [db2].[meta].[DatabaseSettings] WHERE Entry = 'Version'
UNION SELECT 'db3', Value FROM [db3].[meta].[DatabaseSettings] WHERE Entry = 'Version'
UNION SELECT 'db4', Value FROM [db4].[meta].[DatabaseSettings] WHERE Entry = 'Version'
```

Comment: You could use registered servers for each db in [SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1996/registering-sql-server-instances-for-easier-management/) and type `SELECT DB_NAME(), Value FROM [meta].[DatabaseSettings] WHERE Entry = 'Version'`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I'll give it a look, thanks

Comment: also, please use UNION ALL as you don't need to distinct the output of this query most likely (assuming value is a key on the table you have).  The elastic query feature will let you run a single query that does fan-out from one db to N as you request